# compute yolo v1 loss when output w,h is negative

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, yolo

[image: yolo loss function]

Then I start to train my model, the output w and h is a negative value, I don't know how to compute the loss in this situation. I can't find any description in the paper.

Comment: have you figured it out?